# How can I develop dynamic only HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html

**Background:**
My current working environment involves many navigation links that constantly updates, but the system admin will not allow PHP (or any dynamic server). This is frustrating.

**Question:**
Is there a way to implement a class-like structure for HTML using JS to have a makeshift PHP method "include" in my HTML?

**Example:**
For instance, I really appreciate how in PHP I can modularize the navigation links on the top of my website to a file called navbar.php and then include it to all my separate pages. Once a change has been made to the navbar.php, all the other pages will reflect the changes. Unfortunately, my workflow forces me to update all the webpages in a menial fashion. Is it possible to use JS?

Thanks!

Comment: The trivial answer to your question is "yes" -- it is possible.

Comment: @KRyan Cmon man, be more helpful than that. It doesn't take a degree to deduce the question here.

Comment: @dudewad: I'm thinking about how, I was just trying to give the guy hope `;)`

Comment: You're not using "only HTML" you're able to use Javascript. VERY different situations.

Comment: I recall a time, before PHP, when using Dreamweaver templates would update the navigation on all HTML files.

Comment: why not to get a cheap PHP hosting ? . but this is an interesting question :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a js file that dynamically creates nav bar on page load and place it in all pages, you can also check which page it is using `documnet.location` and highlight and all. One change in this file and all pages change

But this will be against graceful degradation, if JavaScript is disabled!!! your site is without any main navigation menu.
You will have to find a work around. Create a basic pure html navigation bar, that contains your consistent links.
Include a js file that replaces this with a better bar, like said above.

Comment: It's basically *the* solution; the tricky bit is figuring out the best way to actually do it. But still, +1 for mentioning graceful degradation.

Comment: Thank you. Based on the responses, this seems like the way to go - I'll try this idea out.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting HTML code into DIV can be done easily using the [jQuery HTML function](http://api.jquery.com/html/) and the [jQuery Load function](http://api.jquery.com/load/).
Basically, you give it a div and HTML code or an url and it will automatically, fill the div with the HTML page from the given URL.

As far as I've seen, you should be able to implement any dynamic behavior your might need using solely jQuery. There are still some limitation like persistence for example and your client must have JS activated for this to work (But let's face it, 99% of the customers does).

Answer (score 0):

Why yes. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes
Server side includes could go a long way towards helping you with this. It's probably the closest you can get.

Comment: Considering his sys admin's ban on "any dynamic server," there's a really good chance that he has not implemented any kind of SSI.

Comment: He'll have to look into it to find out. Either way, it's something to try.

Comment: yes i agree with KRyan, if they dont allow php, good chance they don't allow SSI

Comment: I was unawares - I've never used SSI's so I dont understand the requirements behind them. :S Either way, the answer above this one seems to be what I'd prefer anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Create the navigation menu in pure HTML. Then, create a main `div` for the content of the page, leaving it empty. Finally, use AJAX to retrieve the content of each page (as a separate pure-HTML file) and replace the contents of the main `div` with it.

You can use the AJAX functions of the jQuery framework.

Comment: I think you've got this backward -- you'd want an empty div that you use AJAX to load the navbar into, with the actual content of the page being just written normally.

Answer (score 0):

You could use html object tag to include html too see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp